# Cannot open localhost in new tab after running npm run dev on terminal

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite

I am trying to automatically open the localhost on a new Google window every time I run npm run dev -- --open --port 3000.

What I have tried is based on this discussion https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8467

On server I have the below configuration on **vite.configuration.js**:

```
        server: {
        port: 'https://localhost:3000/',
        open: true
    }
```

But, I am getting this error ->

```
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn undefined\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  path: 'undefined\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAGwAbwBjAGEAbABoAG8AcwB0ADoANQA1ADAAMAAwAC8AIgA='
  ]
}
```

Node.js v20.11.1

I am coming form Angular background and running ng serve --open never caused me an issue.
For this project I use React ^18.2.0, node.js v20.11.1 and Vite ^4.4.5.

It seems that I miss something or a file (ENOENT) but, I not sure.

Please provide me with any feedback or an idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the [discussion](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8467) that you provided, the "port" property does not have the full link. You should only specify the port.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As the other user mentioned above. You should not use a full URL in the port option. Try changing it to 3000 and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeap you have right about the port and I have changed it to 3000. But still get an error Error: spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT. Do I need some permissions or some environment variable to run "vite --open"?

Comment: I am not sure but you do not need vite --open if you already have it in your config.

Answer (score 0):

the port type is number, read the [document](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options)

```
server: {
   //port: 'https://localhost:3000/',
   port: 3000,
   open: true
}
```